# Finding the xpath label @for tag's child

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
>     <div class="grid_8 alpha participant-info-fields">    
>                       <label for="grandTotal"><b>Grand Total:</b></label>
>                       $10,280.55
>                   </div>
```

This is the html that I am trying to get to the $ amount.
I have tried **`//label[@for="grandTotal"]/child::node()`**

This only highlights the GrandTotal text. Since there is no attribute for the $ amount, I am not able to locate it.

PS: I can get to the node with the following: `**//*[@id="planForm"]/div[3]/h3/div/text()**` but this does not work since Selenium only works with Element nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text ***$10,280.55*** is within a text node. So to print the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *childNodes*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'alpha participant-info-fields')][./label[@for='grandTotal']]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'alpha participant-info-fields')][./label[@for='grandTotal']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[4])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This works like a charm. However, for java I had to tweak a little bit.
String test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'alpha participant-info-fields')][./label[@for='grandTotal']]")).getAttribute("innerHTML").split()[3]

Comment: @BornToBeAGamer Oops, I assumed you were with Python.